# Best way for a parent controller to access child controllers' properties

Tags: ember.js

What is the best way for a parent controller to access it's children controller's properties?

This is what I have so far:

```
App.ParentController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'child',

    total: function(){
      return .... whatever    
    }.property('_subControllers.@each.selected')
});
```

I would've thought this would get updated when selected changes but it doesn't.  [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3312) pull request may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding an array to a controller and need to sum some properties? You should be using an ArrayController and using a computed property to sum the values from each array item. If not, then I'd push this down into the model. It seems wrong for a parent controller to be iterating over the child controllers.

Comment: Controllers seem to be the logical place for computed properties that are not stored in model data.  If a parent controller needs to be aware of it's children's computed properties it seems right that it should be able to access these? vs first storing them in model.  e.g. a sum of sums.

Comment: Also I should've used ArrayController and have changed it accordingly.

Comment: Having done some more research on the matter it seems to me confusion reins in ember land re the roles and responsibilities of the various MVC components.  Would be really useful if someone provided a definitive description of each items role.  [this](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/core-concepts/) is inadequate  Also many many examples tend to use different items to achieve similar outcomes leading to more confusion.